# ¿Como puedo generar un json en sql server?

Tags: sql-server, json, sql-server-2012

Buen día gente tengo la siguiente consulta estoy tratando de generar una archivo json en sql server para poder consumir una api atraves de la misma pero al tratar de hacerlo con json path me da error de sintaxis en la consulta y he estado buscando otras soluciones y todo lo que encuentro es similar a lo que tengo implementado

--Tabla Temporal

```
CREATE TABLE #TemporalT1 (
    SurveyID NVarchar(50),
    Operator NVARCHAR(255),
    Store NVARCHAR(255),
    SellerName NVARCHAR(255),
    ClientName NVARCHAR(255),
    ClientMail NVARCHAR(255)
    )
```

--Consulta para llenar la tabla temporal

```
    insert into #TemporalT1 (SurveyID, Operator, Store, SellerName, ClientName, 
    ClientMail)
    select DisTinct 'DFW4343dsdf34cDSCDS', emp.Descripcion, tie.Descripcion, 
   CONCAT(usu.Nombre, ' ', usu.Apellido_Pat) AS Usuario,
   CONCAT(cli.Nombres, ' ', cli.ApellidoPat), cli.Rut_Cliente from Ges_Empresas emp
   inner join Ges_Tiendas tie on tie.Cod_Empresa = emp.Cod_Empresa
   inner join Ges_BlvCabecera blv on blv.Cod_Tienda = tie.Cod_Tienda
   inner join Ges_Usuarios usu on usu.Usuario = blv.Usuario_Vendedor
   inner join Ges_Clientes cli on cli.Cod_Cliente = blv.Cod_Cliente
   where Convert(date, blv.Fecha_Emision) between '20240228' and  '20240229'
```

--Consulta para convertir los registros en json

```
   SELECT
   SurveyID AS SurveyID,
   Operator AS Operator,
   Store AS Store,
   SellerName AS SellerName,
   ClientName AS ClientName,
   ClientMail AS ClientMail
   FROM
   #TemporalT1
   FOR JSON PATH;

   Drop Table #TemporalT1
```

--Error que me da sql server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que error te da? porque por lo menso la sintaxis esta bien

Comment: Lo que muestras, técnicamente no es un error. Probablemente estás usando una versión vieja del SQL Server Management Studio, y al lanzar la consulta se va a ejecutar sin problemas o, de plano, usas una versión vieja del motor, que aún no soportan JSON path, en ese caso si habría un error, con un mensaje generado desde el motor. Si la memoria no me falla, esto se soporta desde la versión 2016.

Comment: era un error de versión ya que estoy usando SQL server 2012, y json path o json auto esta implementado desde la versión 2016, la solución era convertir la consulta a XML y de hay convertir a json

Answer (score 1):

Solución ya que era un problema de version

```
SELECT CAST(
(
    SELECT 
        SurveyID AS 'SurveyID',
        Operator AS 'Operator',
        Store AS 'Store',
        SellerName AS 'SellerName',
        ClientName AS 'ClientName',
        ClientMail AS 'ClientMail'
    FROM
        #TemporalT1
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('SurveyData'), TYPE
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS JSON_Output;
```

Answer (score 1):

Dado que SQL Server 2012 no tiene soporte para el formato JSON, una solución es *armar* la respuesta, por ejemplo, concatenando primero los nombres de los campos y los valores (siguiendo las reglas de tipos de datos del formato JSON) y encerrando cada *objeto* (fila) entre llaves (`{}`), luego concatenando las distintas filas separadas por comas y, finalmente, encerrando todo el *arreglo* entre corchetes (`[]`).

Para lograrlo, podemos valernos de

- la instrucción `for XML` para obtener una concatenación de registros,
- la función `stuff()` para eliminar la coma adicional que agregamos

Por lo que puedo ver, todos los campos de tu consulta serían strings, por lo que voy a encerrar los valores entre comillas.

Esta consulta me devolvería el equivalente de las filas en formato JSON:

```sql
SELECT   '[' 
       + STUFF((
           SELECT   ',{'
                  + '"SurveyID":"' + SurveyID + '",'
                  + '"Operator":"' + Operator + '",'
                  + '"Store":"' + Store + '",'
                  + '"SellerName":"' + SellerName + '",'
                  + '"ClientName":"' + ClientName + '",'
                  + '"ClientMail":"' + ClientMail + '"'
                  + '}'
             FROM #TemporalT1
              FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, '')
       + ']' AS JSON_Output;
```

Como este:

```json
[{"SurveyID":"DFW4343dsdf34cDSCDS","Operator":"jachguate","Store":"Cayalá","SellerName":"Andres","ClientName":"Pedro","ClientMail":"pedro@ejemplo.com"},{"SurveyID":"DFW4343dsdf34cDSCDS","Operator":"jachguate","Store":"Cayalá","SellerName":"Andres","ClientName":"José","ClientMail":"jose@ejemplo.com"}]
```

**Muy importante** tener en cuenta que este código no está listo para producción, es un ejemplo de la ruta que puedes seguir para obtenerlo. Haría falta asegurarse de usar el formato correcto según los tipos de datos y aplicar secuencias de escape a las cadenas que puedan contener comillas dobles `'"'`, para evitar producir JSON mal formado.